# Getting user mentions from video description (v3 API)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a way to know through the Youtube Data API whether `@[some string]` in a video description is a mention (described [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9637404?hl=en)), as well as get the URL/ID of the channel that is being mentioned? I'm retrieving the video descriptions through `/videos?part=snippet&id=<video id>`, but sometimes `@[some string]` refers to a different social media handle (like Twitter) and other times it may refer to a YT mention; however, I don't see any difference between the snippet's description for those two cases. Is that information accessible through the API? Thanks for any help.

Comment: The answer to your question is, unfortunately, negative. But you may well try to file a feature request to Google through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: Thank you for commenting- I'll do that!