How do I check for mentions via the yt api?
I mean, the title explains it self. How do I do that? (preferably via atom/rss?)
I was going to use the push notification thing but it doesnt have it.
Preferably getting the url with the mention. (I can add why I need that but I cant be bothered :3)

For info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66234305/getting-user-mentions-from-video-description-v3-api

In what data are you looking for mentions? Video description, comment...?

I was looking for when @'ts me in a comment
